# Issue between android:windowLightStatusBar and Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android

I have set `android:windowLightStatusBar` to `true` to display black icons and text on status bar inside my app as picture below.

[image]

However, the Navigation Drawer no longer fit to the screen, see the picture below. This is because to ensure `android:windowLightStatusBar` works, `android:windowTranslucentStatus` must be set to false. Any workaround? App like Google Calendar seem to work fine with this feature.

[image]

Here's my main activity's XML

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorToolbarBackground"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
  >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/app_bar" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"

        app:menu="@menu/navigation_view_items" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Would you like NavigationDrawer overlap statusbar ?

Comment: Yes, like Google calendar

Comment: Please add your layout.xml

Comment: I added the xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line from `layout.xml`

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

And add this to `styles-v21.xml`

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

in `styles.xml`

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

in `Manifest.xml` add this in your Activity Main

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
```

And wrap `AppBarLayout` tag into this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!-- Here AppBarLayout ecc -->

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<!-- Here NavigationView ecc -->
```

AppBarLayout must have

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
```

Comment: it works now, you're genius, can you explain why wrapping with a CoordinatorLayout make it works?

Comment: CoordinatorLayout is used for a specific interaction with one or more child views, have a look here [CoordinatorLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html)